# Image doesn't get added to PDF

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, jspdf

I got the following function to add an image to a PDF using JsPDF and calculate the width automatically with the ratio:

```
function addImageAutoWidth(image, x, y, height) {
  const img = new Image();
  img.src = window[image];

  img.onload = function() {
    const aspectRatio = img.width / img.height;
    width = height * aspectRatio;

    doc.addImage(img, 'PNG', x, y, width, height);
  };
}
```

And I call it as following:

```
addImageAutoWidth("img_months_" + currentMonth, startPos[0], startPos[1], 20);
```

"img_months_01" is a global variable containing base64 data.
Everything loads correctly. I logged all the arguments to the console within the .onload function. The base64 image data is correct, the X and Y coordinates are correct and the size is correct. The console gives no error either.

Adding an image without a function (something like this: `doc.addImage("img_months_01, 0, 0, 100, 20)`) works without problem.

But with the function the image doesn't show up in the PDF. Anyone knows what I could've done wrong?

Comment: Perhaps you should discard the loaded image after you've used it to determine the dimensions and instead of `doc.addImage(img, 'PNG', x, y, width, height)` you should use the code that already works, with the computed width param, something like this: `doc.addImage("img_months_01", x, y, width, height)` - In one version you're passing a variable with the data, in the other you're passing a loaded image. In one version you're specifying the image type and in the other you're not - yet the function name appears to be the same - and as such will expect the same input. Unless I overlook something.

Comment: I can't pass the image variable to the function directly, since I use the function to add multiple images. I use this in a for loop: `addImageAutoWidth("img_months_" + currentMonth, startPos[0], startPos[1], 20);`. The image type is defined in the function, so I don't need to add it to the function parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the doc object is passed as a parameter to the addImageAutoWidth function.

```
 const doc = new jsPDF();
 addImageAutoWidth(doc, "img_months_01", startPos[0], startPos[1], 20);
```

and inside the function save the pdf document

```
function addImageAutoWidth(doc, image, x, y, height) {
......
doc.save('__.pdf')

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried it before with the doc parameter. Didn't work either :/ And I can't save the PDF within the addImageAutoWidth function since I dynamically use the function for multiple images.